# Loading a csv file on local system to redshift database

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to load a csv file which is present on my local system to my redshift database. What are the options I can use to upload it?
I am currently using Dbeaver for the db connection and tried importing the data directly. However, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Redshift can't see your local machine. Transfer it to S3, then Redshift can read it. Or write A Lot of insert statements.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

Comment: Agreed. Also, please note that using `INSERT` to insert bulk data is not recommended. The correct method is to load via Amazon S3.